# Mono and sqlbulkcopy

Tags: mono, sqlbulkcopy

Does the mono sqlbulkcopy work? I'm reading data from oracle into a datatable then bulk copy into sql server. Does it have something to do with varchar? It is working fine outside mono, but get errors when running under mono such as:

> While reading current row from host, a premature end-of-message was encountered--an incoming data stream was interrupted when the server expected to see more data. The host program may have terminated. Ensure that you are using a supported client application programming interface (API).

Any help would be appreciated.